# Three.js ReactJS integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

```
import THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.js';

function Thbox(props) {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    };
            return ;
}

export default Thbox;
```

I am getting 'cannot read properties of undefined' on:
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

What is the issue and How to fix this ?[image: Err_console]

Comment: You might have a look at https://discourse.threejs.org/t/best-way-to-integrate-plain-three-js-inside-a-react-app/27049. It doesn't sound like you can simply import the library and use ThreeJS.

Comment: I have simplified the question.

Comment: Forget it, Here is the answer, https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction, https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber